# Python Count UNIQUE occurences...not total count. HOW?

Tags: python, count, unique, counter, tweets

UPDATE:  The following code seems to do the trick:

```
        for word in words:
            if word not in unique_words: ##skips replicates in a given list
                unique_words.append(word)
```

I can not figure out, for the life of me, how to count the number of lists a word is found in, not the number of times a word is found amongst the lists.

If I set up a counter...it counts the occurrence of the word. However, I need something that will, as it iterates through lists of words (each list is a tweet), count a word's UNIQUE occurrences (e.g. number of tweets that have the word). Counters, as I know how to use them, and same with the collections Counter...count all instances.
the

FYI...what the loops are iterating over are tweets, each of which the .split() function was applied to...so, each tweet is a list of words.

This is the code I have that isn't doing what I need it to do.

```
        sentiment = 0   

        for word in words:
            if word in AFINN:
                sentiment += AFINN[word]                

        for word in words:
            if word not in AFINN and word not in new_sent:
                new_sent[word] = sentiment
                tweet_count[word] = 1

            elif word in new_sent:
                new_sent[word] = new_sent[word] + sentiment
                tweet_count[word] += 1
```

ALSO...I have the two word in words statements because it was the only way that I was able to get the TOTAL sentiment score, not just the score up to the point where the new word was found. I'm thinking, though, that if I 'returned' sentiment, that I might not need the dual loops? But, for now, that's not my biggest concern.

THANKS!!!

Comment: The code is deriving sentiment scores for words not contained in a predefined dictionary (AFINN).  So, AFINN  has a bunch of words as keys, and an integer as its value.

Comment: AFINN is my sentiment analysis word list available from http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/publication_details.php?id=6010

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand correctly you have a bunch of tweets and you want to check how many times a certain word appears in those tweets?

```
count = 0
for tweet in tweets:
    if word in tweet:
        count += 1
```

of course if you wanna really not be verbose about it...

```
sum([word in tweet for tweet in tweets])
```

protip: try sum([True, True, True, False, True])

If I misunderstood something let me know.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
tweets_with_word = defaultdict(int)

for words in tweets:  # `tweets` is the "outside" list of word lists
    for word in set(words):
        tweets_with_word[word] += 1

    for word in words:
        ...  # The rest of your code
```

Basically, use `set()` to get a list of unique words in each tweet, then count just those instances.

Comment: I can't back up to "words in tweet" because they won't match...the words have been scrubbed, made lower case, and split...and renamed "words."  And I don't want ALL unique words in the tweets...I want a collapsed tweet containing words not in AFINN.  

So, using set() as described won't do what I need.

Comment: I think Kirk Strauser's version is what you want. You can always do a set difference if you want to exclude words, e.g., `set(['hello', 'there', 'world']) - set(['there'])`

Answer (score 0):

In the update you write (at the very to of your post):

`for word in words:
    if word not in unique_words: ##skips replicates in a given list
        unique_words.append(word)`

Now I am confused. If that is just what you want, then why not just use `collections.OrderedDict`:

`from collections import OrderedDict
words = ['good', 'good', 'bad', 'terrible', 'lucky']
unique_words = OrderedDict.fromkeys(words)`

There is no need of all this control structure.

If the order of the words does not matter then just use `set`:

`unique_words = set(words)`

Comment: I thought about copying from the keys...but what I need is the number of tweets that contain the new words. Copying the keys/set will only give me the word...and copying the values will give me the total number of occurrences. However, by looping back through the tweets, I get a +1 for each tweet that contains a word not contained in your AFINN-111 list. The objective is that a sentiment score is derived for each word not in AFINN by: E(tweet sent score)/(count of tweets containing word), where E is summation across all tweets having word. Is there another way to achieve the same objective?

Comment: BTW...I can't back up to "words in tweet" because they won't match...the words have been scrubbed, made lower case, and split...and renamed "words".